# Replacing integers with the arithmetic mean of its neighbors on a $m\times (m+1)$ grid

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Consider a $m\times (m+1)$ board that is filled with integers. Each turn, one chooses a square, and replaces it with the arithmetic mean of its neighbors. Is it possible to make all the numbers equal after some finite number of turns?

I know that if each number on the grid is equal to the arithmetic mean of its neighbors, all the numbers on the grid must be equal. However, I'm sure if this is useful, and even if it is, I'm not sure how it can be used. Next, I tried some smaller grids. For example, if a $2\times 3$ grid is filled with the integers $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$ in that order, the numbers can never be equal, because $4$ of the numbers can equal $3$, but the last two numbers get infinitely close to $3$. I'm not sure how to continue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the integers are arbitrary right ? If they are all equal to begin with or if $m=1$, the problem is trivial so you probably wanted to exclude those.

Comment: Correct, the integers are arbitrary. I have just seen the problem to prove that all the squares if equal if each of the squares is equal to the average of its neighbors. I was just wondering if this result is useful.